# Method Clear Cache DonutOutputCache

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, caching

Hi all I am working on this method that give how result one page cached:

```
[DonutOutputCache(
        Options = OutputCacheOptions.NoCacheLookupForPosts,
        Duration = 3600,
        Location = OutputCacheLocation.Server,
        VaryByParam = "*",
        VaryByCustom = "SurveySession(calculationReference)")]

    [AuthoriseIntermediaryInSameOrganisation("calculationReference")]
    [HttpGet]       
    public ActionResult Details(string calculationReference)
    {
        .....

        return View(model);
    }
```

In this page I have a partial view (calculationNotes) with one form and I would that when I submit the form the page clear the cache and recharge the mother view (Details)
This is the action for the submit form where I am trying to clear the cache.

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CalculationNotes(CalculationNotesViewModel model)
    {
           ...

        var cacheManager = new OutputCacheManager();
        cacheManager.RemoveItem("Calculation", "Details");

        return PartialView("_CalculationNotes", model);
    }
```

But don't clean the cache I would that when I do the submit of the form the cache is rebuild so that the first actionresult Details will be recalculate.

Comment: Please explain what "doesn't work". Does it throw an exception (`System.DoesntWorkExcpetion`)? please supply the error message Does it behave in way that is different to what you expect? Please explain how you expect it to behave versus how it actually behaves.

Comment: @BenRobinson Might be tougher than it sounds for OP, based on the sentence attempt _"Hi all I am working on this method that result a page cached"_.

Comment: No don't throw an exception, don't give an error in debug work fine but the cache is not clear